# Why does GDB not create symbol file?

Tags: debugging, gcc, compilation

I have a problem when compiling multiple files into an executable.
My command to GCC is:

```
gcc -g -o PartitionedHashJoin -O0 -msse4.2 -lm -DNUM_BUCKETS=2 Relations.h Relations.c PartitionedHashJoin.h PartitionedHashJoin.c
```

GCC compiles it correctly, but apparently does not create a DSYM (Mac OS) symbol file.
I tried stripping the SSE or -lm compiler options, but to no effect.

Does anyone of you have an idea how I can get my debug symbols?

Thanks!

**Update/Edit:**
I'd settle for the embedded symbols, it does not have to be a DSYM file, but the embedded ones seem to be missing, too. `dsymutil` is unable to find them in the executable created with the command above.

Comment: Make sure that `dsyumutil` is installed in your system and read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850788/prevent-compiling-from-generating-dsym-on-os-x-using-make/5391173#5391173).

Comment: The utility is installed - thanks for the hint. When calling the utility, it complains about missing debug symbols inside the executable - apparently they are not created there either.

Comment: Also try -ggdb, but not sure it'll help.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Nope, no effect, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

On other Unixes and Linux, gcc emit debugging information inside the object files. I don't know what is happening on MacOSX.

Comment: dma_k's link pointed out that the symbols should reside in the object file for Mac OS X, too. However, I (or `dsymutil`) can't seem to find them - do I need to specify a location to save them to when calling gcc?